# How to graph data from Firebase

Tags: graph, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

total noob here.
I am pushing radiation values every 5 minutes into a Firebase database and I am looking for a simple way to create a live line graph, which also shows all the data of the last 24 hours.
I managed to create a graph which updates live, but it does not show past data. I have no idea how to accomplish this. I really hope someone can help me.

Here's my java script controller.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var gammaArray = [];
    var tArray = [];
    var sessionArray = [];
    var currGamma = '';

    var dataRef = new Firebase('https://xxx.firebaseio.com/readings');
    dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var t = snapshot.val();
        var count = 0;

        for (var key in t) {
          if (t.hasOwnProperty(key)) {          
            var dt = [];        
            dt[0] = count;
            dt[1] = parseFloat(t[key]);
            gammaArray = [];
            gammaArray.push(dt);
            tArray = [];
            tArray.push(dt[1]);
            count++;
          }
        }
        sessionArray.push(gammaArray[0])
        //console.log(gammaArray)
        $.plot($("#chart1"), [ sessionArray ]);
        currGamma = gammaArray[0][1].toString();
        $('#gammaMsg').show();
        $("#currGamma").text(currGamma);
    });         
});
```

And here's my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.6/firebase.js'></script>     
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
        <div><h1 id='gammaMsg' style='display:none;width:550px; margin:0 auto;margin-top: 50px;'>Current radiation: <span id="currGamma"></span> mSv</h1></div>
        <div id="chart1" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div> 
    </div>
</body>
```